# Measure - Cumulative Totals

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, m, measure

I'm aiming to calculate a cumulative total for Income Accounts and cumulative periods.

However the formula below returns a number that is far different from I expect.
Leaving the formula with the period filter returns all cumulative amounts which is fine.

However everything changes when I add the additional Account Filter.
Any suggestions on what's not working/missing?

(edit --> removing the ALL in the AccountFilter VAR disables the cumulative impact and returns data for the period only).

Thanks

```
OS_PAF_INC_YTD:=
VAR AccountFilter = FILTER(ALL( 'GP Data'),'GP Data'[Rubric 1] ="01. Income")
VAR PeriodRange = FILTER(
        ALL (  'GP Data'),(  'GP Data'[Period] <=MAX('GP Data'[Period])
                     )
            )
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        -   [Sum of AMOUNT] ,
                PeriodRange,
                AccountFilter
            )
```

Comment: Can you share your sample data? Also, why don't you combine the two filters in one query / var?

Comment: show your sample data, what filtering your are applying and what is your expected output.

Comment: I put the two filters in order to isolate the issue. I can be put in one too.
From the data below I would want to filter to Period 2 and get the cumulative sum of 
the Amount column which would be 46,151,886. Filters are one Period,  BFA ( can have BUDGET,ACTUAL etc.) This table is linked to lookup tables which contain hierarchies for Periods ( Calendar ), Accounts, Cost Centres etc.

Comment: link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-yOSVoUjmnYXgIwxfwt_TN4DTzyYBbV/view?usp=sharing